# Use Dynamic classname in php

Tags: php, class, object, dynamic-programming, extend

I have a file which contains a class.
This class extends another class (class1).

I need to extend the class1 multiple times. Here the first lines which create the class.

```
function your_shipping_method_init() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
            class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
```

I have an array which different shipping methods. Thats why I need to load this file a few times.

I tried this:

```
function your_shipping_method_init() {
            if ( ! class_exists( $classname ) ) {
                class $classname extends WC_Shipping_Method {
```

Is there a way, to give a class a dynamic name?

[Here you can find the whole code:](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mikejolley/6713608/raw/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: Class name should be an `identifier`. You cannot use dynamic string as a class name

Comment: There is very rarely a good reason to dynamically generate code of any sort, so perhaps there is an assumption here that you need to review. For instance, if you need a set of very similar *objects*, then you only need one class, and can create as many *instances* as necessary, setting properties on each to represent the different configurations. Or if they are very different, you are presumably writing the code for those differences somewhere, so can define separate classes in the normal way.

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to declare a class inside a function too..

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only using `eval()` function:

```
eval('class $classname extends WC_Shipping_Method { ... }');
```

Comment: eval is not an ooption

Comment: How do you mean it is not an option? You cannot just use variable as class name.

Comment: Many Virus Plugin will detect eval as a malicious function

Comment: So then you must choose some other way as "Dynamic class names" :)